# What software can I use to rotate a video?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing, rotate

I took video with my Sony Cyber shot holding the camera sideways to get a taller capture.  I didn't realize that the video would playback sideways.  Does anyone know of a app. to rotate the video?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/rotate-video-vertical-clips-90-degrees-virtualdub/2657/), most video editing software includes this option, including Windows Movie Maker.  It also mentions that for custom angles (i.e. besides 90 or 180 degrees), [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) can do the trick.

Comment: MovieMaker steps --> http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/mediaadvice/0075.mspx#EPD

Answer (score 2):

With a recent version of ffmpeg, you can do this from the command line, utilising the [transpose](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v 'transpose=1' -c:a copy -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

This will rotate the video 90 degrees clockwise; use `'transpose=2'` to rotate it 90 degrees anti-clockwise. This will require re-encoding the video, for fine-tuning the quality of the results, see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).